# What's the difference between the versions of Cards Against Humanity?

Tags: cards-against-humanity

I have version 1.3 of Cards Against Humanity, but it's got different cards than the free to download PDF file.  Which cards are different between the various versions of CAH?  Since I've also got some blanks from the expansion pack, I'd like to make some new cards without duplicating anything.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Changes to the base game are discussed [here](http://boardgamegeek.com/thread/852358/cah-version-change-to-1-3-new-cards). There is also some additional information on this [thread](http://boardgamegeek.com/thread/779103/new-cards) included photos showing old and new versions.

Between the original and version 1.2, it seems like they got rid of a lot of cards that mention proper names. It seems that cards mentioning Glenn Beck have been removed in 1.3. The second post indicates that at least 8 black cards were replaced and 80+ white cards were changed (though some changes seem small) between the version that came out in early 2012 and the previous one.

[This page](http://boardgamegeek.com/filepage/83028/cards-against-humanity-first-expansion-1-2-changel) also has a link to a PDF file (must login) that lists some changes for the first *expansion* (v1.2 Changelog). Here is a summary:

A bunch of white cards were added:

- A pluger to the face
- The ooze
- Clenched butt cheeks
- Stockholm Syndrome
- Salvia
- Syphilitic insanity

Some white cards removed:

- Appreciative snapping
- Dancing with a broom
- Good grammar
- Pistol-whipping a hostage
- Slow motion
- The Fanta girls

A few minor corrections as well.

A bunch of black cards were also modified:

- Orig: My plan for world domination begins with _ / New: He who controls _ controls the world
- Orig: Science will never explain the origin _ / New: Science will never explain _
- Orig: Next season on Man vs Wild, Bear Grylls must survive in the depths of the Amazon with only _ and his wits / New: This season on Man vs Wild, Bear Grylls must survive in the depths of the Amazon with only _ and his wits

Comment: please summarize the contents of the links to prevent link rot

Comment: I summarized to some degree, but the original photos are the best source since there are quite a few differences.